# efficiently insert diagonal in sparse matrix in julia

Tags: julia, sparse-matrix, finite-element-analysis

I'm studying EM computational methods on [this resource](http://emlab.utep.edu/academics.htm). These methods use a lot of [big sparse matrices](http://emlab.utep.edu/ee4386_5301cmee/Topic%207a%20--%201D%20FDM.pdf#page=33) with only few diagonals set to non-zero. So my question is this: how do I efficiently set a diagonal of the existing matrix  in place in julia?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use indexed assignment:

```
julia> using SparseArrays, LinearAlgebra

julia> S = spzeros(10,10)
10×10 SparseMatrixCSC{Float64,Int64} with 0 stored entries

julia> S[diagind(S)] = rand(10); S
10×10 SparseMatrixCSC{Float64,Int64} with 10 stored entries:
  [1 ,  1]  =  0.2907
  [2 ,  2]  =  0.451863
  [3 ,  3]  =  0.920742
  [4 ,  4]  =  0.0674684
  [5 ,  5]  =  0.587077
  [6 ,  6]  =  0.61916
  [7 ,  7]  =  0.450401
  [8 ,  8]  =  0.596222
  [9 ,  9]  =  0.597324
  [10, 10]  =  0.210721
```

Comment: Yep. `fillband!` function does exactly this anyways

Answer (score 3):

Seems like there's a function [`fillband!`](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/v1.1.0/stdlib/LinearAlgebra/src/dense.jl#L199-L214) that fills space between two diagonals with value, but for some reason it's not exported form the module.